# Any difference between XXX are nice and XXX are nice people

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-difference

I was watching a video about travelling around the world. They had covered 12 countries in three months.

I wanted to leave a comment but was not sure if sentence 1 and sentence 2 are different in meaning.

> Sentence 1: The XXX Country residents (e.g. the German, the Japanese, the Spanish) were nice.
>   Sentence 2: The
>   XXX Country residents were nice people.

Comment: I don't think using "The XXX country residents" is appropriate. For example, "The United Kingdom residents were nice (or nice people)" would not be a good sentence. Can you tell us which country you are referring to by "XXX Country"?

Comment: Thank you for the help, Rathony. I have added some examples of these XXX country residents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There really isn't much of a difference between the two sentences.

> The [group of people] were nice.

is the same as saying

> The [group of people] were nice people.

because the people after the nice is implied because the subject of the sentence are people already (a group of people are people, otherwise it'd be a group of something else).

The second sentence explicitly states what the word *nice* is referring to.

Answer (score 3):

They are the same!  The second sentence just has a little more description with it.  "Nice" is the adjective you're using to describe the residents in both sentences.

Here's what each sentence is referring to (using "Germans" as an example):

> Sentence 1: The **Germans** were **nice**.
>
> Sentence 2: The Germans were **nice** **people**.

Same exact meaning, slightly different (grammatically) as to which specific word "nice" refers to.